# How many daily users to consume the free limit in FireStore 5 Collection 30 documents in each one

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]5 collections and each one in it contains the same number of documents as in the picture, use a listener, can this be very expensive if you upgrade the plan, how many daily users approximately to consume 50,000 readings

Comment: This depends on much more information than what you've given here, and probably than what you know at the moment.  Things like where you use `get()` or realtime listeners, how often the documents are modified, how long listeners are active, all impact this.

Comment: I am a beginner and I do not know much so far, but suppose that I display the data in the worst and most consuming way. Will the number of documents in the image cost me astronomical sums, knowing that I add approximately 15 new documents per day

Comment: You can read all the quotas for free tier [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#free-quota).

Comment: I know that, but I mean, is it possible to exceed 10 million readings if I use a listener and approximately 5 collections that contain more than 30 documents and the number of users is 200 days

Comment: Your assumption can be measured up. Try to provide some numbers for "how often the documents are modified" and "how long listeners are active" and calculate the cost.